# Extract values from JSON text field for use in "IN" statement SQL

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, azure-sql-database, deserialization

In Azure SQL server. I have the following (non-functional) query that is attempting to use the values from a JSON array of foreign keys to find rows, using "IN".

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table WHERE foo_table_id IN (SELECT json_ids_field FROM bar_table WHERE bar_table_id _field= 1);
```

However this returns an error because it does not natively understand the JSON format found in `json_ids_field`.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[29,56,57,71,138,145,195]' to data type int
```

How can I deserialize  this field so that its values are aggregated into a list that can be used in the IN clause.

Comment: You can't take a JSON object and just compare it to an `int`. You need to transform that JSON object into a dataset (of `int`s) and compare to that. Have you had a look at `OPENJSON` to consume your JSON data?

Comment: I have looked into OPENJSON but it says that it OPENJSON is supposed to be used in place of when you would use a table name and I am struggling because in theory the select statement could return multiple rows. So I am not sure how to loop over each.

Comment: You don't loop at all; you use `OPENJSON` in the `FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to use `OPENJSON` to consume your JSON and convert it into a data set:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.foo_table
WHERE foo_table_id IN (SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int, OJ.value)
                       FROM dbo.bar_table bt
                            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(bt.json_ids_column) OJ
                       WHERE bt.bar_table_id_column = 1);
```